# iOS Application is getting crashed after 180Sec when it's in background

Tags: ios, background, crash, ios12

Getting below logs from console (this is not happening in debugging mode even in simulator too)

```
Can't get most elevated app state from dictionary {
BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.App.Stage";
SBApplicationStateKey = 0;
SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = PID;
SBApplicationStateRunningReasonsKey =     (
            {
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = "Shared Background Assertion 2 for com.App.Stage";
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 4;
    }
);
```

}

Here is the Crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace ASSERTIOND, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b0ce3ea4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b0ce337c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b10e8be8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b10e3a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b10e31f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b335c584 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001de478c00 UIApplicationMain + 212
7   App Stage                       0x00000001059c13b0 0x104a0c000 + 16470960
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b0ba2bb4 start + 4
```

Comment: I google'd your error message and found complaints about it crashing in react-native. You haven't mentioned these in your question or the tags, are you using it? Also please describe any background tasks that you are running (if any)

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Thanks for response, This is native Application we are not using any react-native code even in any pod which I am using.

Comment: ... and are you using any background modes? are you executing code when the app goes into a background state

Comment: I removed all code which is executing in background but problem not solved, whenever I get above logs app restarts. we are handling background tasks with ExpirationHandler too.

Comment: OS kills apps that are in background for longer period. Every app gets certain time to stay alive in background. Unless your app registered with particular background modes related to audio/location it won't stay alive forever.

Comment: @SandeepKhade 3 minutes is the standard cut off time for background execution unless a background mode has been specified. I suspect you have something (like a web socket or a networking request) that is doing something in the background. Without knowing anything about your code or use case, I'm not sure what can be done for you

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I am updating location in background for which I have enabled location updates in Background Modes in Capabilities. no socket request.

Comment: @SandeepKhade so again, without seeing your code (you've posted none) People here can only make guesses. I see `UIKitCore` in the stacktrace, so I suspect you are trying to do more than just location updates in the background as you've said, but also possibly trying to update the UI. Googling pieces of your error an stacktrace is returning similar complaints about not properly handling a background task and leaking the memory, such as this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88529 . Have a look at this or post all of your necessary code to debug. Can't do anything without it

Comment: Hey @SandeepKhade did you find any fix?

Comment: @tudorprodan Yes it was because of Third Party Library which was causing this Issue.

Comment: @SandeepKhade what library?